# How can I return a react component using withStyles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-with-styles

The question here is not about how to export, but, how to return a React object with the css injected?

I'm trying to achieve something like it:

```
return ( withStyles(this.props.style)(<Component {...params}/>) );
```

Where the intention is to return **Component** with all CSS set using **withStyles** and with its styles injected in the property called **style**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`withStyles` HOC takes class/function and returns decorated class/function. That's why we cannot pass there component instance(`<Component {...params}>` creates/returns object under the hood).

Having this in mind and JSX's requirement to have component's name started from Capital letter we can do next:

```
const StyledComponent = withStyles(this.props.style)(Component);
return <StyledComponent {...params} />;
```